# What type is 'double x[]' in c++?

Tags: c++, types, structure

I am working with a piece of code that creates a data structure and puts in it 2 values. It looks like this:

```
void func() {
    double x[] = {y, z};
}
```

What is the type of the object `x`? I am trying to return it from a function, so I need to specify the type.

I tried this, but it breaks with `error: no viable overload '='`

```
double func() {
    double x[] = {y, z};

    return x;
}
```

Comment: By "structure" do you mean "type"?

Comment: `x` is an array of `2` `double`, the type is `double[2]`, but you cannot return that from the function.

Comment: @RandomDavis yes, sorry.

Comment: You may or may not have trouble with this, as arrays are only sometimes copiable.

Comment: Try `std::array<double, 2>`

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  In it they will go over arrays and how you can use them.

Comment: @ThomasSablik: You can... and it would be wrong (the return type would be inferred as `double*`, a dangling pointer to a no-longer existing object).  Demo: https://rextester.com/BDSP1549

Comment: You cannot "return" this array, no matter what it's type is, from the function. Any attempt to do so will only end in tears.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: You can return it as `std::array` just fine (maybe with help from `std::to_array()`.

Comment: An alternative is to place the array into a `struct` and pass the struct by reference to the function.